# using multiple variables in loop using scanf

Tags: objective-c, c

I am a real beginner to programming. And I mean REAL beginner. My code I am trying to create is for this question: *Write a program that will prompt the user for 10 ages and then calculates and outputs the average of those ages.
You should not have ten scanf statements in your program. Instead, the scanf statements should be within a loop.*

I have managed to get the loop running and it asks for the statements, but I don't know how to get my variable to add all the numbers inputted up at the end. Instead mine just deletes the old number in the variable and stores the new one, so when I get to the end, it says that the total was the last number entered into the input.

```
@autoreleasepool 
{
    int counter;
    int ages;

    for (counter = 0; counter < 11; counter = counter +1) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Type your age:");
        scanf("%i", &ages);
    }
    NSLog(@" Average age is: %i", ages);
}
return 0;
```

There it is.

Answer (score 0):

See comments in the code as a explaination.

```
@autoreleasepool {

    int counter;

    int ages;
   // add result variable
    int result = 0;

    for (counter = 0; counter < 11; counter = counter +1) {

        NSLog(@"Type your age:");

        scanf("%i", &ages);
        // Add the age to the result
        result += ages;
    }
    // Calculate average
    NSLog(@" Average age is: %f", result/10);

}
```

Comment: thankyou very much for that. Just wondering, how does the line result += ages work? is that how you store it and if so could you tell me how that works for the future?

Comment: This line result += ages is short way of result = result+ages. There are also shorts like -=, *=, \= and the basic is the same, for example a *= b is equal a = a * b, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum them up in a loop and take average outside

```
int counter;
int ages;
int sum = 0;
for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1) {
    NSLog(@"Type your age:");
    scanf("%i", &ages);
    sum += ages;
}
sum /= 10
NSLog(@" Average age is: %i", sum);
```

Comment: thankyou very much for that. Just wondering, how does the line sum += ages work? is that how you store it and if so could you tell me how that works for the future?

Comment: `sum += ages` is a simplified expression of `sum = sum + ages` so as `sum /= 10` is equivalent to `sum = sum / 10`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the sum of the ages, before you can calculate the average:

```
int total;
```

Also the loop goes from `0` to `< 10`, not `< 11` (which is 11 ages).

Therefore:

```
#define NUM_AGES 10

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        int total = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < NUM_AGES; counter++) {
            int age;
            NSLog(@"Type your age:");
            scanf("%i", &age);
            total += age;
        }

        NSLog(@" Average age is: %i", total / NUM_AGES);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thankyou very much for that. Just wondering, how does the line total += age works? is that how you store it and if so could you tell me how that works for the future?

Comment: @user3283315 It's a shorthand for `total = total + age`, just as `counter++` is shorthand for `counter = counter + 1`.